# Accessing PleX server from the same machine but different network (VPN)

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, localhost, plex

My computer is constantly connected through both my home network and my VPN from IVPN, but all programs are set to ignore the VPN by default using OpenVPN and [this](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/IgnoreRedirectGateway) method.

I am then only connecting Chrome to the VPN by launching it through [ForceBindIP](https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip).

The PleX Server I am trying to access is running through my default private network as intended, and thus has the fixed local IP of `192.167.178.43`. I can verify this on the PleX settings page.

The local address for my VPN network is randomized each time it connects.

Before I started using a VPN I could access my PleX server through Chrome by just going to `127.0.0.1`, but this no longer works. I assumed that I would now have to connect to the exact IP of the network that PleX is running on, i.e. `192.167.178.43`, but that didn't work either.

What I actually need to connect to was the random local IP I got from the VPN.

I don't have a lot of experience with networking, so I don't know what my options are here, but connecting to the random IP from the VPN every time I want to access PleX is going to get very annoying. This is amplified by the fact that I apparently need to enter my PleX password every time I try to log in with a new IP as well.

I thought about forcing PleX through the VPN with ForceBindIP, to have it on the same network as Chrome, but if my VPN loses its connection even once I'd have to restart PleX.

Is there any way I can get a fixed IP to the PleX server? It would be ideal if `localhost` could somehow connect to it, since that is the IP that gets called when double clicking the PleX icon.

Answer (score -1):

Hey So I found out that I have the similar issue but I am not sure how I got around this but I did.

Place your plex server in your startup folder and restart the computer.
For some reason when my expressvpn loads up it allows it to run but for some reason if I close my plex and restart the expressvpn forgets about that it alloud it to happen.

I dont know I am sorry for not giving you something more technical.

Modem is Motorolla Arris 
Windows 10 Pc
ExpressVPn 
Plex(Plex SOnarr Radarr)

Comment: I ended up getting a separate machine for my Plex server, and switched from accessing it through the browser to the Plex Media Player.

Since that program is never connected to the VPN I can access the Plex server just fine. Not really a solution to my original problem, but it's what I've ended up with.